# Java 8 lambda expression changes Collection multiple times

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following classes:

Doer, which just executes the run-method of the Runnable (will be a lambda):

```java
public class Doer {
    final Runnable runnable;

    public Doer(final Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Storage, which is a Observable number store:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;

public class Storage extends Observable {
    final List<Integer> storage;

    public Storage() {
        this.storage = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void add(int number) {
        storage.add(number);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(number);
    }

    public List<Integer> getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }
}
```

Filter, preventing the Doer from doing so much ;)

```java
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Filter implements Observer {

    final Doer doer;
    int counter;
    final int nth;

    public Filter(int nth, Storage store, Doer doer) {
        this.doer = doer;
        this.nth = nth;
        store.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == nth)
            doer.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now consider the following Unit Test:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class FilterTest {

    @Test
    public void testStore() throws Exception {
        List<Collection<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        Storage store = new Storage();
        Filter filter = new Filter(2, store, new Doer(() -> {
            numbers.add(store.getStorage());
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }));

        System.out.println(numbers);

        store.add(1);
        System.out.println(numbers);

        store.add(2);
        System.out.println(numbers);

        store.add(3);

        System.out.println(numbers);

    }
}
```

It produces the results:

```java
[]
[]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

I really do not get the last line, why is the 3 now in numbers, since numbers.add(3) has not been executed in the lambda?

Comment: What are  you trying to do here? And why do you write a wrapper for a `Runnable` that does not add any value?

Comment: This is a minimal working example of a bigger application, trust me it makes sense ;)

Comment: *"since numbers.add(3) has not been executed in the lambda?"* that seems to be right, but that doesn't matter much, because the *3* has been added to the single `Collection` inside of the `numbers` list. Your filter can't do anything about it, because it can't prevent modifying the `storage` list in the `Storage` instance.

Comment: @Tom this is the answer, you should post it as an answer

Comment: I doubt that this will at all work as you intend. If you `add(4)`, you would get `[[1, 2, 3, 4][1, 2, 3, 4]]`. Even is this a stripped down version of your original, I think there are too many conceptional issues here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda is called only once. It's adding the `List<Integer>` that's inside `store` to `numbers`.

Note that the lambda is not making a copy of the `List<Integer>` in `store`. So, `numbers` contains a reference to the same `List<Integer>` as what is in `store`.

If you add more numbers to the `List<Integer>` in `store`, you see those changes also in `numbers`, because the content of `numbers` is a reference to the same `List<Integer>`.

So when you do `store.add(3);` and then print the content of `numbers`, you'll also see the `3` in there.

Try making a copy of the collection when you add it to `numbers` in the lambda, and see the difference:

```
Filter filter = new Filter(2, store, new Doer(() -> {
    numbers.add(new ArrayList<>(store.getStorage()));
    System.out.println(numbers);
}));
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your code is really supposed to do, I assume your `numbers` collection is not declared correctly:

```
List<Collection<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is a list of collections of integers, so every element of your list is supposed to be a collection by itself. Instead, it should probably be just a list of numbers:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

So you will also have to change the `Runnable` too, as you don't want to add the entire storage to your list but just the content of the storage:

```
() -> {
    numbers.addAll(store.getStorage());
    System.out.println(numbers);
};
```

Comment: I do not want to modify the structure of numbers, but your answer brought me on the right track.